# eslint parsing error: Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, eslint

I'm using node v7.10.0 that supports ES6 and because of that I don't transpile my code.

ESLint v3.19.0 gives a error `Parsing error: Unexpected token =>` at the following code.

**Give errors:**

```
module.exports = {

    index: async (req, res) => {
        await functionThatReturnsSomePromise();
  }
}
```

Also when I just use function it fails with the error `Parsing error: Unexpected token function`

**Give errors:**

```
module.exports = {

    index: async function(req, res) {
        await functionThatReturnsSomePromise();
  }
}
```

When I define a class like this the linter doesn't complain about it:

**No errors:**

```
class test {

    testing() {
        async () => {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
}
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "binaryLiterals": true,                    // enable binary literals
     "blockBindings": true,                      // enable let and const (aka block bindings)
     "defaultParams": true,                     // enable default function parameters
     "forOf": true,                             // enable for-of loops
     "generators": true,                        // enable generators
     "objectLiteralComputedProperties": true,   // enable computed object literal property names
     "objectLiteralDuplicateProperties": true,  // enable duplicate object literal properties in strict mode
     "objectLiteralShorthandMethods": true,     // enable object literal shorthand methods
     "objectLiteralShorthandProperties": true,  // enable object literal shorthand properties
     "octalLiterals": true,                     // enable octal literals
     "regexUFlag": true,                        // enable the regular expression u flag
     "regexYFlag": true,                        // enable the regular expression y flag
     "templateStrings": true,                   // enable template strings
     "unicodeCodePointEscapes": true,           // enable code point escapes
     "jsx": true                                // enable JSX
  },

  "env": {
    "browser": false,     // browser global variables.
    "node": true,        // Node.js global variables and Node.js-specific rules.
    "es6": true,          // for ES6
    "amd": false,         // defines require() and define() as global variables as per the amd spec.
    "mocha": true,       // adds all of the Mocha testing global variables.
    "jasmine": false,     // adds all of the Jasmine testing global variables for version 1.3 and 2.0.
    "phantomjs": false,   // phantomjs global variables.
    "jquery": false,      // jquery global variables.
    "prototypejs": false, // prototypejs global variables.
    "shelljs": false      // shelljs global variables.
  },

  "globals": {
    // e.g. "angular": true
  },

  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 7,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        arrowFunctions: true,
        defaultParams: true
      }
  },

  "rules": {
    ////////// Stylistic Issues //////////

    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,      // disallow dangling underscores in identifiers


    ////////// ECMAScript 6 //////////

    "no-var": 2          // require let or const instead of var (off by default)
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I use a different linter that works fine.

I'm now using eslint 3.10.1

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem by editing:

```
parserOptions.ecmaVersion = 8
```

async/await is in ES8 (aka ES2017) which I considered is in ES7

Comment: yeah actualy the version what related to the node version not the ecma version.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only valid answer here. Using package to handle that kind of error is very heavy instead of understanding the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code needs to be transpiled, have you tried to use the [babel-eslint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser) parser?

To do so, install the `babel-eslint` package and include in your `.eslintrc.json` (or js equivalent):

```
{
  (...)
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  (...)
}
```

Comment: I dont transpile my code, I work with node v7.10.0. I Updated the question. thx. I also have the error when I use the old function method. Maybe its because its a JsonObject like structure that it doesn't work? instead of a class...